# Why doesn't this fork loop work as expected?

Tags: windows, perl, multiprocessing, fork, activestate

Why does the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;  

my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(5);

my @all_data = ('a','b','c','d','e','f');

foreach my $data (@all_data) {
    # Forks and returns the pid for the child:
    my $pid = $pm->start and next; 
    print "Hello $pid\n";
    $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
```

print:

```
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0
```

I am new to Perl and I am trying to catch up on multiprocessing in Perl

Comment: I am on Windows and I use `#!/usr/bin/perl`.Just noticed that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs for the `start` method](https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager#start-process_identifier):

> This method does the fork. It returns the pid of the child process for the parent, and 0 for the child process.

As it happens, the `fork` function does the same, which is why `start` mirrors it.

The parent may need the child PID to control the child – sending signals and stuff – but the child knows its own PID via the `$$` variable:

```
foreach my $data (@all_data) {
    $pm->start and next; 
    print "Hello $$\n";
    $pm->finish;
}
```

Example output:

```
Hello 22215
Hello 22218
Hello 22219
Hello 22217
Hello 22220
Hello 22216
```

Comment: This snippet is from http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm. My understanding is that `$pm->start and next;` would do `next` for the parent (since ppid !- 0)  i.e. keep forking and execute the print for the child since `$pm->start and next;` would evaluate to `false` since the pid from `$pm->start` would be 0

Comment: @Cratylus That is exactly what it does! However, because `start` returns zero in the child, which you assign to `$pid`, every child prints `Hello 0`. You want to use the `$$` instead to get the PID in the child.

Answer (score -1):

my $pid = $pm->start and next;

"and" logic will evaluate to true if both of the arguments are true. If the first argument is false, then the "and" logic will shortcut and will not evaluate the second argument

You might want to use "or" logic instead.

Comment: `start and next` is the correct convention, as used in the Parallel::ForkManager documentation.

Comment: @AKHolland, yes corect. But that documentation assumed that the program want to do something in the child process. But in this case, it want to do something in the parent process (printing the child pid).